# Oracle Plsql Date Time Manipulation

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I have two different date values stored in a variables inside a PLSQL function.

**Date A:**

```
2011/05/20 08:00:00
```

**Date B:**

```
2015/07/15 00:00:00
```

I need to add the time part of Date A into Date B.
I need to get following result:

**Date C:**

```
[2015/07/15] + [08:00:00] = 2015/07/15 08:00:00
```

Note:
I need to store the result in a `DATE` type variable for further calculations.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the data type of those two variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very suggestive but in your particular case you can use this formula:

```
C = B + (A - trunc(A));
```

Explain: (A - trunc(A)) returns time difference in "days" (in your case the difference is 8 hours this means 8/24 days = 0.33(3)days. After this you add this difference to B (I hope everything is clear).

Answer (score 3):

I'm hard-pressed to imagine that your data types are correct if you're trying to this sort of manipulation.  Perhaps `date A` should really be an `interval`, for example.

Something like

```
c := b + ((cast a as timestamp) - cast(trunc(a) as timestamp))
```

would appear to do what you want.  If `a` was an `interval` rather than a `date`, though, you could just add it to `b` without having to cast to a `timestamp` and subtracting two timestamps.

Comment: In my case Date A and Date B are oracle `DATE` datatypes. Do i have to change anything in above example?

Comment: @Rahul - No.  This works with dates.  But if this is how you are using the data, it is highly likely that your variables should not be dates.  You're seemingly using `a` as an `interval` so it probably ought to be declared as an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
DateC := to_char(DateA,'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' ' || to_char(DateB,'HH:MM:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this asnwers your question. Let me know for any issues.

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  lv_time    TIMESTAMP;
  lv_ol_time TIMESTAMP:=TO_TIMESTAMP('2011/05/20 08:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
  lv_nw_time TIMESTAMP;
  lv_hr      VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT EXTRACT( HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('2015/07/15 08:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) hr
  INTO lv_hr
  FROM DUAL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT :1 + INTERVAL '''|| TO_CHAR(lv_hr) ||'''' || 'HOUR' || ' FROM DUAL' INTO lv_nw_time USING lv_ol_time;
  INSERT INTO test_date VALUES
    (lv_nw_time
    );
END;
```